# Need a Regex that extracts a string between two "delimiting" strings

Tags: java, regex

I need to get the string between **by_** and **_on**.
So far I have this, but don't understand how to truncate the actual "string delimiters":
`by_(.*)_on`

Sample input:
*Files_by_wesasegeaazedude_on_January_26.jpg*
Current Match:
*by_wesasegeaazedude_on*
Needed Match:
*wesasegeaazedude*

Comment: Java, but I'm testing it on RegExr.com

Comment: See [*Java Regex Capturing Groups*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969436/java-regex-capturing-groups)

Comment: usually its the first index(not 0) that contains the first captured group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is good<sup>*</sup>. All you need to do is extracting the content of the first capturing group:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("by_(.*)_on");
String str = "Files_by_wesasegeaazedude_on_January_26.jpg";
Matcher m = regex.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String res = m.group(1);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/AqCRvN)

<sup>*</sup> Well, almost good. If you expect inputs with multiple file names on the same line, you may want to consider using reluctant qualifier, i.e. `by_(.*?)_on`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use *positive lookarounds*:

```
String regex = "(?<=by_).*(?=_on)";
```

What this regex does is:

1. match anything: `.*`
2. that is preceded by `by_`: `(?<=by_)`
3. and followed by `_on`: `(?=_on)`

Comment: Why do you suggest an inefficient pattern? OP has got the same pattern that is way more efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because he is saying that he doesn't want to match the `by_` and `_on`

Comment: @Maljam thanks! it worked

Comment: Worked or not, _Anytime you lead a regular expression by an assertion, you instantly add %200 more overhead._ This can increase by as much as %10-20,000 depending on what follows it.

Comment: @sln so, which expression do you propose? It's good you know all that technical stuff but a quick helping hand is better appreciated most of the time.

Comment: @DevJE - You choose ([Benchmark app](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b4.jpg)). _Regex1:   (?<=by_).*(?=_on)
Elapsed Time:    2.46 s,   2460.14 ms,   2460140 µs
Regex2:   by_(.*)_on
Elapsed Time:    0.39 s,   391.92 ms,   391916 µs_

Comment: @sln you are right, it is more efficient technically, but you are using an example that intentionally chooses a really bad scenario, but if you are using it for file paths, or other small strings, the difference if negligible..

Answer (score 1):

I would do this without regular expressions.

```
int start = str.indexOf("by_");
int end = str.indexOf("_on", start + 1); // or lastIndexOf("_on"), for greedy match.
assert start > 0 && end > start;
String part = str.substring(start + 3, end);
```

Comment: Plus one for a person who do not try to make everything by regex )

Comment: @Sasha I actually misread the question; but I'd still do it without regex :)