# Java replace strings between two commas

Tags: java, regex, replace, split

String = "9,3,5,*****,1,2,3"

I'd like to simply access "5", which is between two commas, and right before "*****"; then only replace this "5" to other value.

How could I do this in Java?

Comment: Nothing. I know s.split; s.replace; s.substring; but How can I first split and then replace?

Comment: You should ask question based on what you have tried and the problem you are facing. You can use regex pattern like this String pattern = ".*(\\d),\\*+"; and create a on that regex Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern); now run matcher object against the text
Matcher m = r.matcher(text); If you group by capture group after checking if any thing found by m.find() then m.group(1) will contain your value. Do Read RegEx & Capturing group in java.Check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969436/java-regex-capturing-groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the following regex replacement:

```
String input = "9,3,5,*****,1,2,3";
input = input.replaceAll("[^,]*,\\*{5}", "X,*****");
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
[^,]*,    match any number of non-comma characters, followed by one comma
\\*{5}    followed by five asterisks
```

This means to match whatever CSV term plus a comma comes before the five asterisks in your string.  We then replace this with what you want, along with the five stars in the original pattern.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: My apologies, @Tim.  I messed up, then we clashed.  Very sorry.  I'm not really trying to be a vandal.

Comment: Many thanks. But could you explain a little bit about "\\*{5}" ? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a regular expression with a lookahead, to find a string of digits that precedes `",*****"`, and replace it with the new value.  The regular expression you're looking for would be `\d+(?=,\*{5})` - that is, one or more digits, with a lookahead consisting of a comma and five asterisks.  So you'd write

```
newString = oldString.replaceAll("\\d+(?=,\\*{5})", "replacement");
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used in the replacement:

```
\\d+           match any numbers of digits, but only when
(?=,\\*{5})    we can lookahead and assert that what follows immediately
               is a single comma followed by five asterisks
```

It is important to note that the lookahead `(?=,\\*{5})` asserts but does not consume.  Hence, we can ignore it with regards to the replacement.

Comment: thx.  \\d+ means digits; while \\*{5} means five asterisks.But i'm still vague about +(?= part; what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

I considered newstr be "6"

```
String str =  "9,3,5,*****,1,2,3";
char newstr = '6';
str = str.replace(str.charAt(str.indexOf(",*") - 1), newstr);
```

Also if you are not sure about str length check for IndexOutOfBoundException
and handle it

Answer (score 0):

You could [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) on `,` and then [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) with a `,` (after replacing `5` with the desired value - say `X`). Like,

```
String[] arr = "9,3,5,*****,1,2,3".split(",");
arr[2] = "X";
System.out.println(String.join(",", arr));
```

Which outputs

```
9,3,X,*****,1,2,3
```

Comment: I think OP is interested in finding the `*****` and replacing the element _before_ it, regardless of its position in the array.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem *between two commas, and right before `"*****"`;* - so it seems the index is fixed (to me).

Answer (score 0):

you can use spit() for replacing a string

```
String str =  "9,3,5,*****,1,2,3";
String[] myStrings = str.split(",");
String str1 = myStrings[2];
```