# Is there a way to know what pattern was used?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to know which pattern was used in this case. I mean sometime i can get input like "123<=456" sometime like "123>=456". My question is, is it posible to know if "<=" was the used pattern or ">="

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<=)|(>=)");
String x= "123<=456"; \\"123>=456"
String[] t = pattern.split(x);
```

Comment: Use capturing groups.

Comment: Match it afterwards.

Comment: You meant "is it possible to write a if condition ?" Yes

Comment: thanks, i found waht i need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969436/java-regex-capturing-groups

Answer (score 2):

## A better way to parse the input

Using this:

```
([0-9]+)(>=|<=)([0-9]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SfDOPE/1)

You can parse `123<=456` into:

- `123`
- `<=`
- `456`

and `123>=456` into:

- `123`
- `>=`
- `456`

Comment: yeah thats the one way, thanks