# RegEx ignore letters until digit occurs and then match letters afterwards

Tags: java, regex

This is intended to be used in Java.
Imagine following sample input:

```
WRA1007
1085808
1092650S
3901823CV
```

I want to match **all alphabetic characters after at least one digit**.

Desired output:

```
S
CV
```

Actual output:

```
0S
3CV
```

My current approach looks like this:

```
\d[a-zA-Z]+
```

The problem with this pattern is that it includes the digit beforehand too. My current solution is to remove the first character of the resulting string afterwards. And this seems quite unsatisfactory to me.

Comment: I think, you'll need groups. This answer should solve you problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969620/4717152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\d)[a-zA-Z]+
```

`(?<=\d)` means "there must be a digit before this position, but don't match it".

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pqyZy3/1)

Alternatively, you can use a pair of `()` to surround the part you want to get:

```
\d([a-zA-Z]+)
```

This is called a "group", and you can get its value by calling `group(1)` on your `Matcher`.

Comment: Just a side note: `\d([a-zA-Z]+)` needs another backslash in the beginning when using with java. Otherwise it's an invalid escape sequence. Works perfectly fine though!

Answer (score 2):

If you 'add' groups you can get group 1 that contain only letters

```
\d([a-zA-Z]+)
```