# Java Regex: Require zero/even amount of backslashes without including backslashes in the match

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that matches all numbers that are surrounded by <@! or <@ and >. The matches must not follow an odd number of backslashes but can follow a zero or even number of backslashes.

Currently, I have this regex:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*(<@!|<@)[0-9]+>
```

The problem is that the matches **include** the backslashes and I need a regular expression that does **not** include the backslashes.

Can anyone make a regular expression that can accomplish this?

Examples:

Valid Input String: `\\<@!123>`
Matches: `<@!123>`

Invalid Input String: `\\\<@!123>`
Matches: none

Valid Input String: `<@123>test<@456>`
Matches: `<@123>, <@456>`

Invalid Input String: `\<@123>test\\\<@456>`
Matches: none

Comment: @anubhava okay sure

Comment: Simply use the capturing group and extract its contents. Use `String regex = "(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*(<@!?\\d+>)"` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969620/3832970 how to get Group values.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Od56i8

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! Your solution worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the substrings you need using the `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(<@!?\d+>)` regex. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZWSqN/2).

The `(<@!|<@)` part in your pattern is matching either `<@!` or `<@` and the difference is only in the `!` char. So, it is logical to replace it with a simple `<@!?` pattern that matches `<@` and then an optional `!` char. Then, capture the whole `(<@!?\d+>` part, and get it with the Java code.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Od56i8):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
 
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "1) \\\\<@!1123> 2) \\\\\\<@!2123> 3) <@3123>test<@3456> 4) \\<@4123>test\\\\\\<@4456>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*(<@!?\\d+>)");
        for (String t: pattern.matcher(s).results().flatMap(g -> Stream.of(g.group(1))).toArray(String[]::new)) {
            System.out.println(t); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<@!1123>
<@3123>
<@3456>
```